# Trouble loading colors using VTKLoader

Tags: three.js, vtk

I am having trouble loading colors from a vtk file using VTKLoader. The image is entirely white. The VTK file is

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
data
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 5 float
 1.5  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.5  0.0 
 1.5  1.5  0.0 
 0.0  0.0  0.0 
-1.5 -1.5  0.0 
LINES 1 3
2 3 4 
POLYGONS 1 5
4 0 1 2 0 
POINT_DATA 5
COLOR_SCALARS lut 4
1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

The function in my html file which loads the image is:

```
function load(datastuff){

var loader = new THREE.VTKLoader();

    loader.load(datastuff, function( geometry ) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );
    })
}
```

I know I can change the color of everything overall using the color: parameter in MeshBasicMaterial, but I was wondering how/if it was possible to color using the VTK data. I've read online that VTKLoader does not support coloring, so I was wondering if there was a way around it, or if you would suggest using an entirely different approach from VTKLoader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, VTKLoader currently does not support colors. Ref: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3429.

See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_colors.html for an example of using vertex colors.

You will have to import the vertex colors yourself -- or better yet, improve `THREE.VTKLoader`. :-)

three.js r.58